# gulp syntaxe error after installation

Tags: node.js, gulp

Ok so I have a problem installing gulp in my project. I followed the steps on the installation guide but I get a SyntaxError when trying to run their default example.

I just installed gulp with : `npm install --global gulp-cli` and `npm install --save-dev gulp`

I created a file named **gulpfile.js** at the parent of my project and then added the following code to the file :

```
var gulp = require('gulp');

gulp.task('default', function() {
 // place code for your default task here
});
```

Then I runed gulp in powershell located at the parent of my project expecting to execute nothing because there is no code in my task but I received the following error :

```
PS D:\Users\UserName\project> gulp
D:\Users\UserName\project\gulpfile.js:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { ��v
                                                              ^

SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
    at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:616:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at execute (C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp-cli\lib\versioned\^3.7.0\index.js:28:18)
PS D:\Users\UserName\project>
```

My gulp version after installation are :

```
[18:56:36] CLI version 2.0.1
[18:56:36] Local version 3.9.1
```

and my npm version is :

```
5.6.0
```

Note that I also tried with actuall task and got the same result

I would like to know what I did wrong or what I need to do to resolve the problem.

Comment: Looks like you have some strange characters in the beginning of your gulpfile (maybe BOM?). Remove them?

Comment: Thanks alot man... I copied and pasted the code so it added the hidden caracters for control V

Answer (score 0):

As Felix Kling said in the comments, there was strange characters in the beginning of my gulpfile.
Indeed, when I copied and pasted the code, it added the hindden caracter for Control-V...